# For exact same JSF EL expression, getter is being called for ouputText but not for inputText. Why?

Tags: jsf

This is my JSF pages

```
<h:form>
      First Name: <h:inputText value="#{userBean.first}" valueChangeListener="#{userBean.updateLastName}" onblur="submit()"/><br/>
      Last Name: <h:inputText value="#{userBean.last}"/><br/>
      Last Name: <h:outputText value="#{userBean.last}"/><br/> </h:form>
```

Following is the managed bean code.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {
    private Map<String, String> names;

    private String first, last;

    public UserBean() {
        names = new  HashMap<>();
        names.put("first1", "last1");
        names.put("first2", "last2");
    }

    public String getFirst() {return first;}
    public void setFirst(String first) {this.first = first;}
    public String getLast() {return last;}
    public void setLast(String last) {this.last = last;}
    public void updateLastName(ValueChangeEvent e){
        last = names.get(e.getNewValue().toString());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    }

}
```

Now, when I type "first1" on the FirstName field and tab out, I see "last1" on the outputText field but inputText field remains empty.

I did the debugging and found getter is being called only once, so I wonder why getter is not being called for the inputText? Considering EL Expression is exactly same and based on my knowledge getter should be called during Render Response phase???

Comment: Off-topic: Why are you implementing it this way? Are you using jsf 1.2? Otherwise it is better to switch to using ajax

Comment: Is it the your request scope? is each of the statements a request?

Comment: @Kukeljet - Yes, I now ajax is better way and it works fine with ajax, but I want to know why this happens?

Comment: @SamOrozco - It is session scoped as you can see in my code.

Comment: I can't see it in your code. It says `@requestScoped`

Comment: Sorry SamOrozco, yes I used @requestScoped in the code, but that won't make the difference, it is just a request scoped conversation any way.